Football kit management system in WordPress
I am new to StackOverflow and familiar with the possibilities of WordPress and the plugins that come with it.
Have build my fair share of WooCommerce websites with all the necassery plugins.
The challenge that I now face is that I would like to create a website for my own football club where the club can manage their inventory of the kits (shirts, shorts, socks, etc) that they hand out to the different teams within the club.
For example, a senior team get at the start of the season 20 pairs of socks, shirts and shorts and needs to hand this in at the end of the season. There needs to be the option to register how many of each items are returned in order keep an overview of the total stock that the club has. This so that the club knows how much to order of these items.
The people who will be handling this process are not the most tech-savy so it must be as simple and clean as possible to prevent an overload of possibilities.
Is there somebody who has experience with building such a site? There is a multitude of plugins available that to a part of this, but I can not find one that does the whole package.
Hope you can help me in pointing me in the right direction. Any hints and tips are welcome.

You're basically looking for an internal inventory system - I build a lot of football related stuff, so I could help you with this, but you'd first need to start putting some code together.  What I would do in this instance is create a 'garment' post-type, or perhaps a 'full kit' post-type if you want to keep sets as one.   What would help you decide the best sort of logic, would be to make a spreadsheet that makes the most sense.  Then the objective is to take that spreadsheet and make your own data sets using custom post-types, taxonomies and possibly custom database tables.

Hi Tony, thanks for your answer. I will have look at the custom post type that can be tailored towards the needs that I have. We already have the Excel to start with. We are trying indeed to replace this Excel with a nice digital experience, so to say.
I have searched for inventory systems but these are 99% tailored towards proper products unfortunally.
Thanks for the tips and if I get stuck with the custom post types, I know wher to go :)
